# New siding and Durofoam eps rigid insulation

Tags: insulation

I have plaster walls inside my house 2x4 stud with paper back insulation. Then I have 3/4” drywall on the outside studs with felt roofing on it then aluminum siding. I removed the aluminum I will remove the felt should I tyvek then install durofoam silver back insulation and tape the insulation or tape the tyvek or both. I plan on strapping the insulation and installing vertical steel siding. I live in southern Ontario.

Also should the silver face be in or out I read that if I’m strapping with 3/4” the silver should face out because it gives extra r value.